# Make bar plot aggregating smaller values

Tags: python, bar-chart, pivot-table

I have an array of values I need to plot from a crosstab dataframe:

```
label        0    1
values          
0          374  294
1           95  122
2           17   22
3            9    8
4            1    4
5            0    3
9            3    1
```

and I would like to represent singularly the values from 0 to 3 (since there are many) and then aggregate values 4 ,5 , 9 into a final bar '4+'.

I am using `pd.crosstab(df.values, df.label).plot(kind='bar'` to plot the bar chart, and I know I should use the aggfunc (and maybe a lambda function?) to aggregate the final values, but I don't know how. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have your exact dataframe but you could apply this solution to your own (might need a little job on the multi-lvel indices or that you change its shape. Anyhow, the idea is the same:

Define the row index from which you want to aggreagate the data, mask it, and aggregate. You will need to rename both the columnss and th sum row

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n = 3

df = pd.read_csv('testingagg.csv', sep="\s+")
df = df.set_index('label')
mask = df.index.get_level_values('label') > n

df1 = df[mask].agg(['sum']).reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'label'}).set_index('label')
new_df = pd.concat([df[~mask],df1]).rename({ 'sum': '{}+'.format(n+1)}).reset_index()

ax = new_df.plot(x="label", y=["a", "b"], kind="bar")
```

which gives:
[image]